# Loading data slow in NEO4J when adding many node properties

Tags: neo4j

I'm attempting to visualize firewall log data. To start, I am using the Windows application firewall logs.

I am using LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS. It works well when I have only a limited number of relationship properties, but as soon as I add just one more property to the relationship, it slows to a crawl, taking upwards of 30 minutes to process.

Example below loads quickly:

```
        $queries['statements'] = @()

        $query = "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data/go_output/$($uuid)_send_data.csv' AS row
        MERGE (from:ipobj {ip: row.srcip, ipversion: row.srcipver, internal: row.srcipinternal})
        MERGE (to:ipobj {ip: row.dstip, ipversion: row.dstipver, internal: row.dstipinternal})
        MERGE (from)-[datatransfer:SENT {date: row.date, type: row.action, size: row.size}]->(to)"
        $queries['statements'] += [ordered]@{'statement'="$($query)"}

        $retval = $queries| ConvertTo-Json

        $url = "http://127.0.0.1:7474"
        $credPair = "neo4j:test"
        $encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair))
        $headers = @{"Authorization"="Basic $encodedCredentials"; "Accept"="application/json; charset=UTF-8";"Content-Type"="application/json"}

        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$($url)/db/data/transaction/commit" -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $($retval)
        $response.content
```

Example below takes 15 minutes to process:

```
        $queries = @{}
        $queries['statements'] = @()

        $query = "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data/go_output/$($uuid)_send_data.csv' AS row
        MERGE (from:ipobj {ip: row.srcip, ipversion: row.srcipver, internal: row.srcipinternal})
        MERGE (to:ipobj {ip: row.dstip, ipversion: row.dstipver, internal: row.dstipinternal})
        MERGE (from)-[datatransfer:SENT {date: row.date, type: row.action, size: row.size, srcport: row.srcport, dstport: row.dstport}]->(to)"
        $queries['statements'] += [ordered]@{'statement'="$($query)"}

        $retval = $queries| ConvertTo-Json

        $url = "http://127.0.0.1:7474"
        $credPair = "neo4j:test"
        $encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair))
        $headers = @{"Authorization"="Basic $encodedCredentials"; "Accept"="application/json; charset=UTF-8";"Content-Type"="application/json"}

        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$($url)/db/data/transaction/commit" -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $($retval)
        $response.content
```

NEO4j complains about an eager operator, but loads just find with only the 3 properties.

Help? I don't know why this is happening. I've checked the query plan and done a bunch of troubleshooting but have no idea why this is happening. To avoid this post being too long, I'm not going to put the troubelshooting, but feel free to ask or just tell me what i'm doing wrong!

**NOTE** the file that i'm loading is, more or less, a standard issue windows firewall (pfirewall.log) file with the following modifications:

- space delim has been changed to comma
- comment rows have been removed and replaced with just the header
- header column names that contained a dash, the dash has been removed (src-port became srcport, etc)
- I did add an ipversion column (ipv4 vs ipv6) and an srcipinternal boolean column as seen in the :ipobj node merge/creation, but those are not explicitly needed. Those are just there for me to do some analytics stuff with later on.
- I actually did some preprocessing to split the files out into SEND/RECEIVED/FORWARD/UNKOWN action types to make processing easier below, which is why the file is called uuid_send_data.csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eager operator is there to preserve Cypher semantics, but becomes a major headache due to its consequences when processing large data sets, such as with a LOAD CSV. There are planned changes to mitigate this, but that's for the future.

More info here:
https://community.neo4j.com/t/cypher-sleuthing-the-eager-operator/10730

For workarounds, we can either do some contortions in the query, or more easily, make this into 3 passes: once to MERGE your `from` nodes, once to MERGE your `to` nodes, and a third to MATCH to both and then MERGE the relationship between them.

EDIT:

Thanks to the query plan you provided, we can see that your MERGEs are not backed by an index, that's why we see NodeByLabelScans in the plan. **Per row**, for each of the two nodes, every single one of the :ipobj nodes is being checked and filtered, and that's not going to be efficient.

You need an index to make this fast.

What uniquely identifies an :ipobj node? If it's just the `ip` property then create a unique constraint on that. If it's a combination of properties, then create a node key constraint, or at least an index on the given properties.

My comments about working around the Eager issue still stand, but you need to support your MATCH and MERGEs (especially when performing loading!) with indexes or constraints to make them efficient.

Comment: This is one of the steps that I had tried and it doesn't seem to have helped.

It seems like the major issue that it's having, is with the number of properties I have on the relationships, but I don't know why.

I also tried below, which ALSO didn't help:

1) Create :ipobj objects
2) Create "action" objects
3) Create "protocol" objects
4) Create "path" objects
5) MERGE (srcip) - [:performed_action] -> (action) - [:via {srcport: "22", dstport: "443", size: "446", tcpflags: "S", tcpsyn: "54", tcpack: "1", tcpwin: "25", info: "-"}] -> (path) - [:using] -> (protocol) - [:from] -> (dstip)

Comment: Oh, maybe your MERGE isn't backed by an index? Try doing an EXPLAIN of the query and attach the plan (with all elements expanded)

Comment: The query I ran is: 
EXPLAIN LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data/go_output/52fdfc07-2182-654f-163f-5f0f9a621d72_send_data.csv' AS row
        MATCH (from:ipobj {ip: row.srcip})
        MATCH (to:ipobj {ip: row.dstip})
        MERGE (from)-[datatransfer:SENT {date: row.date, type: row.action, srcport: row.srcport, dstport: row.dstport, size: row.size, tcpflags: row.tcpflags, tcpsyn: row.tcpsyn, tcpack: row.tcpack, tcpwin: row.tcpwin, info: row.info}]->(to)

https://imgur.com/09V4Y3n

Comment: Thanks, I added on to my answer in response.

Comment: Thanks!

In checking the documentation, I saw that each node created has a uuid associated with it. I (clearly, incorrectly) made the assumption that was the PK and that it would internally use this for query optimization during load operations.

I'll create an index and give it another go here in a moment.

Do you happen to know if it's "good form" to put so many properties on a relationship, or should they be on a node instead?

Comment: It's a good question. Usually it's a good idea to think about whether the thing the relationship is representing deserves to be modeled as its own "thing", in which case remodeling it as a node might be better. Also if you need fast lookup by its properties, that tends to work better as a node. That said, Neo4j 4.3.x just landed, with relationship indexes now native, so the quick lookup part is no longer a factor for deciding how to model it.

Comment: bad news! it does not appear that the index fixed the issue :( It still took 2022062 ms (33 minutes-ish)

I created the index using: CREATE INDEX ipobj_ip_index FOR (n:ipobj) ON (n.ip).

I used PROFILE instead of EXPLAIN to get real times instead of estimated.

https://imgur.com/a/EaQKDNT

Comment: It helped, the NodeByLabelScans would have been a major problem. From the plan we see that the 5705 pairings of nodes that there were over 2 million relationships, so the majority of the time spent has to be on the property access and filtering to those relationships with the given sets of properties.

Comment: yeah, I saw that, but I guess i'm not really sure if there is anything else I can do to speed it up further.

Sorry if i'm asking dumb questions. ...

Comment: Not dumb at all. There's probably not much we can do to improve the query, so you'd next have to consider modeling changes. If you were to encode one or some properties as part of the type (maybe the date, or the action, or both) then selection of the relationship types you want would be much faster than considering them all and filtering. You'd need to leverage APOC to handle the dynamic relationship types, however.